# Do Bayesian Optimization Methods Better Handle "Noisy Functions?"

Tags: optimization

We know that in many applied contexts (e.g. Machine Learning, Loss Functions for Neural Networks), the functions we are trying to optimize are "noisy" by definition (unlike in the classical sense, when we are only required to optimize "deterministic functions"). This is because these functions are based on measurements that we have (i.e. the data), and it is very possible that these measurements can either contain some "measurement error" or these same measurements could take different values if we were to measure them again (i.e. "stochastic").

I have heard that Bayesian Optimization techniques are generally favored for instances where the gradient of the loss function does not exist (e.g. discrete/combinatorial problems) - but I am particularly interested in learning about the effectiveness of Bayesian Optimization Methods on "Noisy Functions". For instance, (my very limited knowledge of this topic tells me that) Bayesian Optimization uses a Gaussian Process to "reconstruct" the surface of the Loss Function based on the data we have , and our confidence in this surface is iteratively updated as we perform the optimization task.

**Is it because of this fact (i.e. modelling the loss surface of the objective function using a Gaussian Process) that Bayesian Optimization methods are said to be effective at optimizing "noisy functions"? Does doing so somehow result in solutions with a higher level of statistical robustness? In general - why do we say that Bayesian Optimization is more effective at optimizing noisy functions?**

Comment: Instead of "we say", perhaps you mean or should write "their proponents say".

Comment: @ Mark L Stone: Thank you! I will keep this in mind!

Comment: I'd be curious to see whether the proponents of robust optimization would find Bayesian optimization preferable to robust optimization with "noisy" model parameters.

Comment: @ prubin: this is a very interesting comment, but I am not sure I fully understand it. Could you please elaborate? Thank you so much!